# K&R C Exercise 3-3 Editing char elements in an array not working?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm currently on exercise 3-3 in K&R C, and I'm confused as to why my solution isn't working.  The goal of this exercise is to pass in two strings, when you encounter something like "a-z" or "0-9" you print out the complete list of whatever the two characters are.  This is my current solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* expand(char s1[], char s2[]);

int main(){
    char s1[100] = {"a-z is higher on the ascii table than 0-9\0"};
    char s2[200];
    expand(s1, s2);
    printf("%s\n", s2);
}

char* expand(char s1[], char s2[]){
    char temp;
    char temp2;
    for(int i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(s1[i] == '-'){
            temp = s1[i-1];
            temp2 = s1[i+1];
            for(int j = temp + 1; j < temp2; j++){
                s2[i] = j;
                i++;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            s2[i] = s1[i];
        }
    }

    return s2;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: After you expand `a-z` into 26 characters, the `else s2[i] = s1[i];` isn't going to work correctly anymore. You need separate input and output indexes.

Comment: Help with what? Read [ask] and follow the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the loop part of the code as suggested by @user3386109

```
int i2 = 0;
for(int i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(s1[i] == '-' && i != 0 && s[i+1] != '\0'){
            temp = s1[i-1];
            temp2 = s1[i+1];
            for(int j = temp + 1; j < temp2; j++){
                s2[i2] = j;
                i2++;
            }
        }
        else s2[i2++] = s1[i];
    }
```

If an expansion takes place, `i` would be garbled for iterating on the actual input `s1`. Hence isolate it.